# Database Connection - Database Design - Parent - Child - child of child

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a Questions on Database Designs - What and how is the best way to do it. this is how i usually do it. ^^

Simple Example: i have 3 Tables

Users Table

```
user_id      name     
2           Name1     
3           Name2
```

Facility Table

```
facility_id      facility_name     user_id
13                facility1            2
14                facility2            3
```

Floor Table                                   ( this is what i do
                                                   i add user id here ^_^ )

```
floor_id      floor_name      facility_id       ( user_id )
5             floor1             13                  2
6             floor2             14                  3
```

So in here You don't have to add user connection to floor table because u have it to facility where floor table is connected..

but i tend to add it anyway for easier Query..   is this a bad Practice?

Comment: Your schema is not completely normalized, but what is your actual question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen .. Uhmm..  if it is good to add the Parent id to every Child of Child.. 

Also how do you normalize that Schema ?.. hmm  for all i know it's already good to go..

Answer (score 1):

I can see the convenience of having `user_id` in the Floor table lets you do a single join to the Users table. There is however a potential for inconsistency. Let's say someone manually entered into the db:

```
floor_id      floor_name      facility_id       ( user_id )
5             floor1             13                  2
6             floor2             14                  2
```

Now if you get to user via facility we get user 3 and if we go directly from floor to user we get user 2.

The consistency can be enforced by specifying that the foreign key relationship between Facility and Floor is on two columns `(user_id, facility_id)`. You can still join Floor to User but there's no way even manually to enter inconsistent `(facility_id, user_id)` into Floor, the pair has to match an existing row in Facility `(id, user_id)`.

Comment: oh...  Haven't Thought of that possibility,  . been coding for years but yet to encounter one(or maybe i did and did not notice) ..  Thanks for that.. 

like i said i Often so it but not always.. 

i created this Question because im so unsure weather to stop doing it .. since i wan't to have a standard coding style.. hehe ..